# Can I use memoir in G5 format?

Tags: memoir, paper-size, dimensions

I'm writing my dissertation using memoir. It will be printed in G5 format (169mm × 239mm). How can I set memoir to use these custom dimensions, while keeping margins etc beautiful?

I understand that memoir allows `\setstocksize{239mm}{169mm}`. However, there's clearly something else needed, and I don't want to mess up a beautiful package by applying my own sense of design.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\setstocksize{239mm}{169mm}
\author{Anna}
\title{This is the sample title in a minimal working example}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You always need `\checkandfixthelayout` and you need to define what the margins for the text are.

Comment: Thank you @daleif! I'll go read the rest of the chapter in the documentation.

Comment: See my answer, I forgot `\settrimmedsize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do

```
\setstocksize{239mm}{169mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{4cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

Memoir operate with stock size and paper size, such that you can define a certain paper size to be printed on a different stock size.

So first we set the stock size, then we use `\settrimmedsize`  to set the corresponding paper size, there they are just the same. Lastly you need to set the text margins and in the end `\checkandfixthelayout` in order to make sure everything make sense